# Is there any way that I could use 'countBy' prefix with my custom query in spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm now using `spring-boot` and `spring-data-elasticsearch` for my java project.

I have to count the number of users who reports some data per day, so I created a custom query for it,

```java
public interface UserInfoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<UserInfo, String> {
    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"username\": \"?0\"}},{\"range\": {\"createdTime\": {\"gt\": \"now-1d/d\",\"lt\": \"now+1d/d\"}}}]}}")
    List<UserInfo> findByUserNameWithinDayRange(String username);
}
```

and get the number of the user by below code.

```java
private long numberOfUser (String username) {
    List<UserInfo> userInfoWithinADay = suggestionRepository.findByUserNameWithinDayRange(ip);

    return userInfoWithinADay.size();
}
```

However, I thought this way is quite inefficient; I don't need the whole list of the UserInfo, just the "hit" info of them.

Could I know is there any way that I could use `countBy` prefix with my custom query, or send `Count API` by using spring-data-elasticsearch? Or are there any way that I could achieve a query that could find a list of data within a day range without defining a custom query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `@CountQuery` instead of `@Query` (or add the parameter `count = true` to the `@Query` annotation) - and change the return value of the repository method to `long`.
2. This should work with query derivation and a method name like `long countByUsernameAndCreatedTimeBetween(String username, Instant from, Instant two)` - I have not tested this. And you would need to calculate the date parameters

I would create a custom repository fragment with a method `long userWithinADay(String user)` and in the implementation I would create a `CriteriaQuery` for the name and the dates and pass that to one of the `ElasticsearchOperations.count()` methods.

Edit:

`@CountQuery` was added in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.

Comment: Thank you so much, P.J.Meisch. Your answer is what I'm looking for. If you don't mind, could you please let me know where could I get `@CountQuery` annotation or using `count=true` param in `@Query`? It seems like I couldn't import `@CountQuery`, and `count` param has not been supported in @Query annotation. (only `value` and `name` could be found.)

Comment: Just one more question; what does your comment means?   
`I would create a custom repository fragment with a method long userWithinADay(String user) and in the implementation I would create a CriteriaQuery for the name and the dates and pass that to one of the ElasticsearchOperations.count() methods.`

Does it mean that you prefer using CriteriaQuery rather than using `Query` annotation on the ElasticsearchRepository? And again, thank you so much!

Comment: I just edited my answer, the changes for `@CountQuery` and the parameter for `@Query` were added in the last version of Spring Data Elasticsearch. As for using `CriteriaQuery` or `@Query`,  that's mostly a matter of taste. I prefer the first, but in your case using an annotated query has the advantage of letting Elasticsearch do the date math.

Comment: Oh I just found that I used `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch (2.4.5)`, not `org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch`. Thank you!